# Should uploading a file be job of a WCF service or asp.net web application that calls the service?

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf

I am architecting an application and need your inputs please:

Asp.net web application calls a WCF service that is running as windows service.

user can log into asp.net website and select a text file and save it in the Database.

Should it be a job of WCF service to take the file from user's machine, save on the server and then read the file locally and save in the database? or, should asp.net website upload the file and send a job to wcf service to load a local file into server?

thanks.

Comment: It depends on what the responsibilities of each (ASP.NET versus WCF/Windows Service) are... but I usually would let the ASP.NET handlet the client-side and the WCF/Windows Service handle the DB part...

Comment: thanks. is uploading a file to server a client side or server side? i am finding it hard to draw a line between client and server.

Comment: first step is client/browser sends you the file... the interface for that is provided by you ASP.NET app (which runs on the server but interacts via the browser with the client)... from the POV of the DB your server is the client...

Comment: ok. so you're saying i should go for second option above?

Comment: as I wrote it depends a bit on the current responsibilities of the two processes but: yes, generally I would opt for the second option

Answer (score 0):

If it were me, I would use option 2: using ASP.NET to retrieve the file, then in code behind, calling the WCF service to actually save/retrieve the file from the database.